# Options matching in a command

Tags: regex

I'm actually creating a discord bot and I'm trying to match some command options and I have a problem getting the value between the square brackets. (if there is)

I've already tried to add a `?` to match one or more of these but it's not working, searching about how I could match between two characters but found nothing that helped me.

Here is the pattern I've got so far : https://regexr.com/4icgi
and here it is in text : `/[+|-](.+)(\[(.+)\])?/g`

What I expect it to do is from an option like that : `+user[someRandomPeople]`
to extract the parameter `user` and the value `someRandomPeople` and if there is no square brackets, it will only extract the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[+-](.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$
```

Or, if there should be no square brackets inside the optional `[...]` substring at the end:

```
^[+-](.*?)(?:\[([^\][]*)\])?$
```

Or, if the matches are searched for on different lines:

```
^[+-](.*?)(?:\[([^\][\r\n]*)\])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wRv6Us/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%2B-%5D(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%5C%5B(.*%3F)%5C%5D)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[+-]` - `+` or `-` (note that `|` inside square brackets matches a literal `|` char)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\[(.*?)\])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (`[^\][]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`)
  - `\]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What's the point of making almost all quantifiers non-greedy?

Comment: @melpomene Actually, my first suggestion was `^[+-](.*?)(?:\[([^\][]*)\])?$`, but it is not a big difference from the one I left (mostly due to the multiline demo, not sure if OP needs to work it on each line - that could be solved with adding `\n` into the character class, yes, but that is when the expression starts looking clumsy). The first `.*?` is necessary, otherwise `.*` will grab all line and won't backtrack much after as the group before `$` is optional.

Comment: Your first suggestion is very different. Consider `+foo[bar[baz]`: The first version matches `'foo[bar'` and `'baz'`, whereas the current answer matches `'foo'` and `'bar[baz'`.

Comment: @melpomene That is not that important for the current scenario as it is extraction, not validation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by validation. All I'm saying is the two regexes extract different things.

Comment: and I know that. At any rate, OP says it is what OP wants.